# Как сделать эффект параллакс с помощью полимер?

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, polymer

Собственно суть сообщения в самом вопросе. Буду благодарен за любую информацию. В сети ее оказалось катастрофически мало.

Comment: Посмотри данный [пример](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html)

Comment: Это же скроллмэджик. А что насчет polymer?

Answer (score 1):

> Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Любая информация: быстрым гуглением нашлось сразу два вариант компонентов Polymer для создания параллакса. [Раз](https://github.com/vguillou/parallax-element) и [два](https://github.com/winhowes/parallax-container). Второй вариант кажется мне лучше, т. к. имеются аккуратные доки и пример в репозитории. Тем не менее, оба решения достаточно давно не обновлялись. Однако, это не мешает как минимум распотрошить их и получить "любую информацию". Тем более, кода там кот наплакал.